# Codeigniter ajax fail to update database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

first, I'm sorry for my bad english, I will do my best to explain my problem.
So I have problem using ajax to send data to controller and then update the model.
Ajax fails to request if I try to update database.

here is my view (ajax):

```
$('#set_online_restricted').on('click', function() {
        var status = "noauto";
        var change_by = "administrator";
        var date = new Date();
        var date_time = (date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getFullYear()+"-"+date.getDate()+" "+date.getHours()+":"+date.getMinutes()+":"+date.getSeconds();
        var message = " ";
        var postData ={
                    'status': status,
                    'change_by' : change_by,
                    'date_time' : date_time, 
                    'message' : message
                };
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '..../index.php/home/set_changed_infos',
           data: postData,
           success: function (msg){
                alert("data saved : " + msg);
                show_service_status ();
           },
           error: function() {
                alert("failed");
           }
        });

});
```

here is my controller :

```
public function set_changed_infos(){
            $this->Manage_service_status->set_service_status();
        }
```

here is my model :

```
public function set_service_status()
    {
            $status = $this->input->post('status');
            $change_by = $this->input->post('change_by');
            $date_time = $this->input->post('date_time');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');

            $data= array(
                'status' => $status,
                'status_change_by' => $change_by,
                'status_change_date' => $date_time,
                'status_message' => $message,
            );
            $this->db->where('name',$pliname);
            $this->db->update('update_service',$data);      
    }
```

$pliname is constant for the moment.

When I click on the button, I get "failed", but when I comment this "$this->db->update('update_service',$data);" the request doesn't fail and my variables are corrects. So I don't understand why?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Can you explain how `$pliname` could be a constant? As I said before, a database update is impossible without a primary key, so what is this record's primary key?

Comment: $pliname is defined as primary key in database. I found the problem, it was the format of dat_time which not respect DATETIME in database.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Controller

```
public function set_changed_infos(){

   if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'){

        $status = $this->input->post('status');
        $change_by = $this->input->post('change_by');
        $date_time = $this->input->post('date_time');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');

        $updateData['status'] = $status;
        $updateData['status_change_by'] = $change_by;
        $updateData['status_change_date'] = $date_time;
        $updateData['status_message'] = $message;

        $pliname = 'something'; // I've not seen where is your $pliname?
        $this->Manage_service_status->set_service_status($updateData, $pliname);
   }
}
```

Model

```
public function set_service_status($data, $pliname){
    $this->db->where('name', $pliname);
    $this->db->update('update_service', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now ajax request doesn't fail but now I think the variables $status, $change_by.. are empty

Comment: when I replace the code exactly with what you suggest, I got failed again :/

Comment: Have you checked the your `$pliname` variable?
Where from it comes?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `where` statement, so CI doesn't know which record to update.
E.g.: `$this->db->where('id', $id);`

You can read more [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update)

Comment: @jani Gvidas is right that this is missing, could you update your question to show where you get your `$id`? In the code you posted there is no record of an id for the record anywhere.

Comment: done. there is no id or otherwise it's a constant for the moment. ($pliname)

Comment: Well, now there's a `$pliname` variable that appears to come from nowhere... You can't update a record without telling the database what the primary key of the record is you wish to update, right? You have to identify that primary key somewhere in your code

Comment: @jani please update your ajax `error`statement to see if any error comes from php: `error: function(data) {
                alert(data);
           }`

Comment: @jani then use `error: function(data) { console.log(data); }` you'll be able to look inside object in console window

Comment: AmrKh had noticed that a condition is missing. it's  `if($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'){ ..]`. He's right, now the request doesn't fail but I think that the variables are empty.

Answer (score 0):

please replace modal function in data ARR

```
$data= array(
                    'status' => $status,
                    'status_change_by' => $change_by,
                    'status_change_date' => $date_time,
                    'status_message' => $message
                );
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the format of date_time, I just switch month with year to respect dateformat( which is DATETIME) in database and now it works. Thank you for your help.